# I want to access 'md_bg_color' from 'tut_1.kv' and change it's value from 'tut_1.py'

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

*I am facing problems in using kvlang with the python code because I am very new to kivy and kivymd, and I am learning kivy on my own.*

I need your help and guidance in learning KIVY.

**I want to access 'md_bg_color' from 'tut_1.kv' and change it's value from 'tut_1.py'.**

***tut_1.py***

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from random import randint


class tut_1(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_file('/home/kali/Documents/Kivy/kivymd Tutorial/kv_lang/tut_1.kv')


tut_1().run()
```

***tut_1.kv***

```
MDScreen:
    id: can
    radius: [90, 90, 90, 90]
    md_bg_color: (1,0,0,.3)
```

***THANK YOU VERY MUCH FOR GIVING YOUR VALUABLE TIME TO HELP ME.***

Answer (score 0):

The `md_bg_color` is just a property of the `MDScreen`. The `MDScreen` is the root of your `MDApp` because is is the `return` of your `build()` method. So, from any method of your `tut_1` class, you can modify `md_bg_color` like this:

```
self.root.md_bg_color = (0,1,0,1)
```

If you are accessing it from outside the `tut_1` class, you can use:

```
MDApp.get_running_app().root.md_bg_color = (0,1,0,1)
```

Comment: Sorry to say sir that these methods are not working in my code. It is giving "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'md_bg_color'"

Comment: Which are you using and where did you put the code?